# Android Path.approximate() usage in pre Lollipop

Tags: android

This method has been around since Lollipop 5.0 but marked as @hidden. It has then been made public in the latest O preview and it can be (most likely safely) accessed via reflection between API 21 and 25.

I'm asking if there is a way to port this back to API 19 and below. Though it seems pretty much impossible since it is relying on native methods.

[Here's](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/graphics/Path.java#Path) the source code for reference.